# Error on text-to-speech api : ReferenceError: speechSynthesis is not defined

Tags: javascript, cordova, vue.js, text-to-speech, quasar-framework

I'm making a program in quasar framework (who works on vue and can be compiled on mobile by cordova). And i'm having some issues to run it on mobile. here's the function:

```
    activateAudio: function(){
      try{
        speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance('hey'))        
      }catch(e){
        alert(e)
      }
```

when i ran this code, i'm take this alert :

> ReferenceError: speechSynthesis is not defined

I also tried to put **window** before the variable. Why this error occurs?

Library followed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/SpeechSynthesisUtterance

Comment: Well, it looks like you're attempting to use the Web Speech API, but this is not running in a browser that supports the Web Speech API. You need to use some provision by Cordoba to access the native speech API with something like [this](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to use the Web Speech API in a non-browser JS environment. Unless your JS environment implements the Web Speech API, you need to find some alternative API that *is* supported by your JS environment.

Given that you're using Cordova, you should probably try using something like this: [cordova-plugin-tts](https://github.com/vilic/cordova-plugin-tts)

Comment: I've already tried to import, but it keep me showing me an alert that he cannot call speak of undefined. Maybe it happens on the compilation? The curious is that the speechSynthesis api from this webkit works fine in this enviorment ...

this is the documentation followed: https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/cordova-plugins

Answer (score 0):

**Try this I hope it will fix...**

```
 let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(`Hey`);

 SpeechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
```

Answer (score -1):

replace this `SpeechSynthesis.speak(utterance)` with `speechSynthesis.speak(utterance)` then it work